# How can I save Login Token in outlook Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, save, token

Im programming an C# Outlook Addin. This Addin should pass some information from an E-mail Item to a Webservice. 
After im logged in on to the Webservice i get some LoginTokens.
My question is where can i save this Login informations, so that I don't need to log in again every time i reopen my Outlook?
My Tokens are 30 days valid, so i dont need every time i reopen Outlook new Tokens.

```
public interface ILoginHandler
{
    string LoginToken { get; set; }
    string LoginSessionToken { get; set; }

    void RequeryCredentials();

    bool LastAuthorizationOk { get; set; }
    bool IsPasswordChangeRequired { get; set; }

    string TwoFactorAuthSessionToken { get; set; }
    bool RememberLogin { get; set; }
    void RequestTwoFactorAuthCode(TwoFactorAuthenticationType type);

    void AfterSuccessfulTwoFactorAuth(LoginReturn.LoginReturnCode loginReturnCode, bool autoLoginSet);

    void ClearTokenAndLogin();
    void PromptPasswordChange();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [StorageItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/storageitem-object-outlook) object for that. Read more about that in the [Creating and Saving Data to Solution Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/creating-and-saving-data-to-solution-storage) article.

```
Sub StoreData()
  Dim oInbox As Folder
  Dim myStorage As StorageItem
  Dim myPrivateProperty As UserProperty

  Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  ' Get an existing instance of StorageItem by subject, or create new if it doesn't exist
  Set myStorage = oInbox.GetStorage("My Private Storage", olIdentifyBySubject)

  If myStorage.Size = 0 Then
    'There was no existing StorageItem by this subject, so created a new one
    'Create a custom property for Order Number
    Set myPrivateProperty = myStorage.UserProperties.Add("Order Number", olNumber)
  Else
    'Assume that existing storage has the Order Number property already
    Set myPrivateProperty = myStorage.UserProperties("Order Number")
  End If
  myPrivateProperty.Value = lngOrderNumber
  myStorage.Save   
End Sub
```

In general, you may treat your C# add-in as a regular managed application and use any way that .net provides or you like.